# Highcharts - Guage - Changing the color and radius of the center black dot(circle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/2/

This is the jsfiddle for the highcharts guage graph. i have tried to change all the options and customise the chart. But not able to figure out the way to change the radius and color of the center dot.

shown in this image below

```
In this example .. how do i change the color and radius of the centre black dot.?
```

[image]

Comment: Also, is there a way to change the text of the number displaying the pointed value to some HTML content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use plotOptions,  see the link below

```
plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                pivot: {
                    radius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    backgroundColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
                        stops: [
                            [0, 'white'],
                            [1, 'gray']
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/8/

Comment: Wow Thanks, Also is there a way to change the text of the number displaying the pointed value to some HTML content ?

Comment: thanks.. but really don't have idea about this.. you can check this from http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the id of the div that contains gauge is "container"

```
var circle = $( "#container").find('circle');
$(circle).attr("r", 7 );
$(circle).attr("fill", 'green' );
```

Comment: You can change the values according to yourself of course, the default values were 5 for radius and 'black' for color.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container").find("circle").attr("r", 15);
$("#container").find("circle").attr("fill", "red");
```

Just manualy find object and set attribute of it.

You can also set `fill` property by css like

```
circle{fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);}
```

But you cannot set radius by css, so I use both js ways.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwxbfu1u/6/